# How to make a react icon with ternary linked to random api data global

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-typescript

I have a component that is gathering random data on each call from an api. In this component I have an icon that is rendered depending on what the weather is like from the api. I'm wanting to render only the icon from this component in another component without having to make another api call.
This is my weather component:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Weather } from '../types';
import { MdWbSunny } from 'react-icons/md';
import { IoIosPartlySunny } from 'react-icons/io';
import { BsFillCloudSnowFill } from 'react-icons/bs';
import { Title, Text, Container } from '@mantine/core';

const WeatherComponent = () => {
  const [weather, setWeather] = useState<Weather | null>();
  const fetchWeatherData = async () => {
    const response = await axios.get('http://mock-api-call/weather/get-weather');

    setWeather(response.data.result.weather);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchWeatherData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <Container>
      <Title order={2}>
        {weather?.forcast === 'Sunny' ? (
          <MdWbSunny data-testid="sunny" />
        ) : weather?.forcast === 'Snowing' ? (
          <BsFillCloudSnowFill data-testid="snowing" />
        ) : (
          <IoIosPartlySunny data-testid="overcast" />
        )}
      </Title>

      <Text size="xl" data-testid="forcast">
        {weather?.forcast}
      </Text>
      <Text size="lg" data-testid="temp">
        Temp: {`${weather?.min} to ${weather?.max}`}
      </Text>
      <Text size="md" data-testid="description">
        {weather?.description}
      </Text>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default WeatherComponent;
```

if I could export weather from this component into my other component I think I would be able to move the ternary operators into the other component.
How can I export this data?

Comment: Is the other component nested within this one? Then you could pass as props, otherwise use context.

Comment: no it's not. Ill look into useContext